# Javascript colon symbol(:) used in conditon of ternary operator

Tags: javascript

```
function Menu(c) {
    var c = {
        names: c.names ? c.names : undefined,
        fonts: c.fonts ? c.fonts : undefined
    };
```

I am new to javascript.
some where i found this code and i am stucked here.

so what i know is
symbol of Questionmark (?) is conditional (ternary) operator.
and its syntax is

```
condition ? value1 : value2
```

So Q.1) why ' : ' is used in condition and value both ?

```
names: c.names ? c.names : undefined,
```

and for reference (names) gives an array of names.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `names: ...` left side is refering to the object's key, and the rightside is refering to the value, which is the result of the ternary operator

Comment: first colon has nothing to with with the ternary operator... `var c = {
        names: "foo", fonts: "bar" }`

Comment: why `var`, where a local `c` is given and why not use logical OR `||`, like `names: c.names || undefined,`?

Comment: Thanks and i Got your Point @NinaScholz . i will try OR operator too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first colon is what separates the key from the value in the object you're building (e.g. `var o = { foo: "bar" }`).

It may help to rewrite it with parentheses:

```
var c = {
    names: (c.names ? c.names : undefined),
    fonts: (c.fonts ? c.fonts : undefined)
};
```